# Adapting IE8 to IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have this code:

```
container = document.getElementById("menuContainer");
```

and later on:

```
    container.document.open("text/html");
    container.document.writeln(content);
    container.document.close();
```

In IE8 works but in IE11 warns me:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: IE11 needs `ownerDocument` here.

Comment: here as container.ownerDocument?

Comment: Yes, that is supposed to work. Though  just `document.writeln(...)` should do as well. `dw()` opens the document automatically, if the page has already been parsed.

Comment: yeah, document alone works but I have more lines as container.document.getElementById("menuItem

Comment: Why? `container` doesn't exist after the first `document.writeln`. By no means to be rude, but are you sure you know what you're doing with `document.write`? If you're not, please don't use it, use for example [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead.

Comment: yes I know. The important thing is not the use of write as I can choose others ways. the problem is the Container.document. which you already solved by ownerDocument. if you write an awnser I will select it as the one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended standard reference from the node to a document has been `node.ownerDocument` since [DOM Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#node-ownerDoc). According to [MDN: ownerDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534315(v=vs.85).aspx) is supported since IE6. In IEs `node.document` was also supported until IE10.

The fix for your code would hence be:

`container.ownerDocument.open(...);`

<sub>`document.write` was used in the example only to demonstrate the output, not as real code, hence I'm not handling its use in this answer.</sub>